# Creating a pandas pivot table to count number of times items appear in a list together

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, pivot-table

I am trying to count the number of times users look at pages in the same session.

I am starting with a data frame listing user_ids and the page slugs they have visited:

```
user_id page_view_page_slug
1       slug1
1       slug2
1       slug3
1       slug4
2       slug5
2       slug3
2       slug2
2       slug1
```

What I am looking to get is a pivot table counting user_ids of the cross section of slugs

| . | slug1 | slug2 | slug3 | slug4 | slug5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| slug1 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 1 | 1 |
| slug2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 1 | 1 |
| slug3 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 1 | 1 |
| slug4 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| slug5 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 |

I realize this will be the same data reflected when we see slug1 and slug2 vs slug2 and slug1 but I can't think of a better way.
So far I have done a listagg

```
def listagg(df, grouping_idx):
    return df.groupby(grouping_idx).agg(list)
new_df = listagg(df,'user_id')
```

Returning:

```
          page_view_page_slug
user_id                                                   
1        [slug1, slug2, slug3, slug4]
2        [slug5, slug3, slug2, slug2]
7        [slug6, slug4, slug7]
9        [slug3, slug5, slug1]
```

But I am struggling to think of loop to count when items appear in a list together (despite the order) and how to store it. Then I also do not know how I would get this in a pivotable format.

Comment: have you tried `df.pivot`?

Comment: Is there a possibility of repetitions in the data? For example, if `(user_id 1, slug1)` repeats, then what should be the result? For the two current answers, it either creates an extra row & column for `slug1` (repeats) or gets added twice and the top row & first column become `[5, 3, 3, 2, 1]`, which I think is more accurate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is another way by using numpy broadcasting to create a matrix which is obtained by comparing each value in `user_id` with every other value, then create a new dataframe from this matrix with `index` and `columns` set to `page_view_page_slug` and take `sum` on `level=0` along `axis=0` and `axis=1` to count the `user_ids` of the cross section of slugs:

```
a = df['user_id'].values
i = list(df['page_view_page_slug'])

pd.DataFrame(a[:, None] == a, index=i, columns=i)\
   .sum(level=0).sum(level=0, axis=1).astype(int)
```

---

```
       slug1  slug2  slug3  slug4  slug5
slug1      2      2      2      1      1
slug2      2      2      2      1      1
slug3      2      2      2      1      1
slug4      1      1      1      1      0
slug5      1      1      1      0      1
```

Comment: I think this one is better, because _if_ there is a repetition, such as `(user_id 1, slug1)`, the top row & first column become `[5, 3, 3, 2, 1]`, which I think is more accurate. In your other answer, it creates an extra row & column for `slug1` (repeats). _(Although, I think `[3, 3, 3, 2, 1]` would be the right result in that case.)_ Wait for OP to confirm [if there can be repetitions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66036510/creating-a-pandas-pivot-table-to-count-number-of-times-items-appear-in-a-list-to/66193929#comment117029555_66036510) and what the result should look like.

Comment: Thanks @aneroid yeah it depends on OP although I haven't checked the results when there is repetition but  I guess `[5, 3, 3, 2, 1]` seems more correct and really thanks for testing the code :)

Answer (score 2):

Let's try `groupby` and `reduce`:

```
from functools import reduce

dfs = [pd.DataFrame(1, index=list(s), columns=list(s)) 
      for _, s in df.groupby('user_id')['page_view_page_slug']]
      
df_out = reduce(lambda x, y: x.add(y, fill_value=0), dfs).fillna(0).astype(int)
```

**Details:**

[`group`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) the dataframe on `user_id` then for each group in `page_view_page_slug` per `user_id` create an adjacency dataframe with index and columns corresponding to the `slugs` in that group.

```
>>> dfs

[       slug1  slug2  slug3  slug4
 slug1      1      1      1      1
 slug2      1      1      1      1
 slug3      1      1      1      1
 slug4      1      1      1      1,
        slug5  slug3  slug2  slug1
 slug5      1      1      1      1
 slug3      1      1      1      1
 slug2      1      1      1      1
 slug1      1      1      1      1]
```

Now [`reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#reduce) the above adjacency dataframes using a reduction function [`DataFrame.add`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add.html) with optional parameter `fill_value=0` so as to count the user_ids of the cross section of slugs.

```
>>> df_out

       slug1  slug2  slug3  slug4  slug5
slug1      2      2      2      1      1
slug2      2      2      2      1      1
slug3      2      2      2      1      1
slug4      1      1      1      1      0
slug5      1      1      1      0      1
```

---

**Optionally** you can wrap the above code in a function as follows:

```
def count():
    df_out = pd.DataFrame()
    for _, s in df.groupby('user_id')['page_view_page_slug']:
        df_out = df_out.add(
            pd.DataFrame(1, index=list(s), columns=list(s)), fill_value=0)

    return df_out.fillna(0).astype(int)

>>> count()

       slug1  slug2  slug3  slug4  slug5
slug1      2      2      2      1      1
slug2      2      2      2      1      1
slug3      2      2      2      1      1
slug4      1      1      1      1      0
slug5      1      1      1      0      1
```

Comment: Nice one. And not a `pivot` in sight! +1 (Because it was obvious that a simple pivot doesn't do what's needed.) Is `s` the Series version of what the OP had at the top?

Comment: @aneroid Thanks! `s` is `page_view_page_slug` per `user_id` so for example for `user_id=1` `s` would be series containing the slug values `['slug1', 'slug2', 'slug3', 'slug4']
` similarly for `user_id=2` `s` would be a series containing the values `['slug5', 'slug3', 'slug2', 'slug1']`

Answer (score 1):

Let's use self-join on user_id with `merge` and `pd.crosstab` to count:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

txt = StringIO("""user_id  page_view_page_slug
1       slug1
1       slug2
1       slug3
1       slug4
2       slug5
2       slug3
2       slug2
2       slug1""")

df = pd.read_csv(txt, sep='\s\s+')

dfm = df.merge(df, on='user_id')
df_out = pd.crosstab(dfm['page_view_page_slug_x'], dfm['page_view_page_slug_y'])

df_out
```

Output:

```
page_view_page_slug_y  slug1  slug2  slug3  slug4  slug5
page_view_page_slug_x                                   
slug1                      2      2      2      1      1
slug2                      2      2      2      1      1
slug3                      2      2      2      1      1
slug4                      1      1      1      1      0
slug5                      1      1      1      0      1
```

For repetition of data, let's try:

```
dfi = df.assign(v_count=df.groupby(['user_id', 'page_view_page_slug']).cumcount())

#Let's filter some unnecessary joins with query
dfi = dfi.merge(dfi, on=['user_id'])\
         .query('page_view_page_slug_x != page_view_page_slug_y or page_view_page_slug_x == page_view_page_slug_y and v_count_x == v_count_y')

df_out = pd.crosstab(dfi['page_view_page_slug_x'], dfi['page_view_page_slug_y'])
df_out
```

Output:

```
page_view_page_slug_y  slug1  slug2  slug3  slug4  slug5
page_view_page_slug_x                                   
slug1                      3      3      3      2      1
slug2                      3      2      2      1      1
slug3                      3      2      2      1      1
slug4                      2      1      1      1      0
slug5                      1      1      1      0      1
```

Comment: Just one merge and a crosstab. Nice! Didn't think to self-join +1. In case the OP responds about [repetition of data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66036510/creating-a-pandas-pivot-table-to-count-number-of-times-items-appear-in-a-list-to#comment117029555_66036510), what would be an ideal change? Currently, it gives `[5, 3, 3, 2, 1]` as the first row.

Comment: Selecting this one as the bounty answer since it applies just `merge` and `crosstab` and less mind-bending to get the required result.